# Display total value of all listbox items

Tags: c#, wpf, listboxitems

I would like to display the total value of all listbox items in to a textbox.

The debugger has shown that the the values are formatted like so: `£00.00\r\n`.

Essentially, I'd like to break down the item string and then convert it to a double (or decimal), adding each item together to finally give the total sum.

I have tried using `.Replace` to replace `£` `\r\n` but this only ever seems to work with the first value and not with the rest.

Any help or suggestions as to how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

(Working with Visual Studio 2012, WPF using C#)

Edit -- Code listing provided:

```
private string trimmed;
private int total;

/// <summary>
/// Calculate the total price of all products
/// </summary>
public void calculateTotal()
{
    foreach (object str in listboxProductsPrice.Items)
    {
        trimmed = (str as string).Replace("£", string.Empty);
        trimmed = trimmed.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
        //attempt to break string down
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listboxProductsPrice.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        total += Convert.ToInt32(trimmed[i]);
    }
    //unsure about this for, is it necessary and should it be after the foreach?

    double add = (double)total;
    txtbxTotalPrice.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", add.ToString());
    //attempt to format string in the textbox to display in a currency format
}
```

When I try this code, the results for `£1.00` and `£40.00` equals `48`. Not quite sure why, but hopefully it will help those with a lot more experience than myself.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we can go from there. As your question stands, it would be impossible to give you a complete and meaningful solution without seeing how your UI elements are created and how you're attempting to perform the calculation. Please edit your question and add the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have put up the code listings. Hopefully the code and comments are self-explanatory, if not, I will amend the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you're entirely replacing the content of `trimmed` at each iteration. I'd change the loop to:

```
foreach (object str in listboxProductsPrice.Items)
{
    trimmed = (str as string).Replace("£", string.Empty);
    trimmed = trimmed.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
    total += Convert.ToInt32(trimmed);
}
```

When you did this

```
total += Convert.ToInt32(trimmed[i]);
```

since `trimmed` is a string, what was happening is that you're adding the value of the `i`th character of the string---which might crash your program if there are more lines in the listbox than there are characters in `trimmed`. You're probably getting 48 since that's the integer value of the character "0".

Comment: Thank you. 

It's not working 100% but you have definitely put me on the right track. 

Seems so obvious when reading it back. Kudos.